# What is the best practice to remove my own tag's contents?

Tags: python, regex, django, string, unicode

I use Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.

I use unicode.

I'd like to remove my own tag's contents.
My own tag name is `<nospeak>`.

For example, if input the message below,

INPUT:

```
foofoo<nospeak>barbar</nospeak>hogehoge
```

The result I hope is there.

OUTPUT:

```
foofoohogehoge
```

*`<nospeak>barbar</nospeak>` is removed

The important thing is that unicode is also included.

I created my method. It runs fine.
But, I used it in Django. It didn't run fine.

Could you tell me the good practice to remove my own tag's contents?

F.I.Y
the method I created.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

def __make_speakable_text(text):
    pattern = r"(<nospeak>.*?</nospeak>)"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

    speakable_text = text

    if len(matches) == 0:
        print 'Not match'
    else:
        for match in matches:
            # print match
            speakable_text = speakable_text.replace(match, '')

    return speakable_text
```

Comment: What's wrong with `re.sub(r'<nospeak>.*?</nospeak>', '', text)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `re.sub(ur'<nospeak>.*?</nospeak>', '', text)`.

To read more on the `u` and `r` before the regex pattern, you can check [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) post.

Comment: stribizhev
Thank you for replying. But, if I use your command. content aren't removed. Only remove tags..

Comment: @shinriyo: Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. But, I don't use contained text
So, I merged your answer and Avinash Raj's answer

finally 

`re.sub(ur'<nospeak>.*?</nospeak>', '', text)`

Comment: @shinriyo: Please check out the link I added to the post. I hope that is quite enough.

Comment: Your old answer is also helped me. But, I can't resolve how to use '\g<1>'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270437/how-to-matchobject-in-python