# How to MatchObject in python?

Tags: python, regex

I use Python 2.7.
And I want to convert url.

What I'd like to is

INPUT:

```
HOGEHOGE<url>http://super.long.url.com</url>BARBAR<url>http://super.long.url.com</url>FUGAFAUGA
```

*the string includes Japanese

OUTPUT:

```
HOGEHOGEhttp://short.urlBARBARhttp://short.url2FUGAFUGA
```

My code is here.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

def __make_shorten_url_text(text):

    def make_shorten_url(m):
        # (1)how to use it??
        long_url = m.compile('\g<1>')
        import urllib
        import bitly_api
        login_name = 'my id'
        api_key = 'my secret key'
        bitly = bitly_api.Connection(login_name, api_key)
        quote_url = urllib.quote(long_url.group(), ':/?&=')
        try:
            result = bitly.shorten(quote_url)
        except:
            return long_url
        return result['url'].encode('utf-8')

    shortened_url_text = re.sub(ur'<url>(.*?)</url>', make_shorten_url, text)
    return shortened_url_text
```

print __make_shorten_url_text('HOGEhttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/29250195/BARBAR')

I use bitly_api.

I want to get url and I don't know how to use '\g<1>' in MatchObject.
The commented-out(1) in my code is that I don't know how to fix.

Could you tell me how to fix it?

INPUT:

```
JAPANESE_CHATACTER<url>https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29250195/</url>JAPANESE_CHATACTER
```

**in Python**

OUTPUT:

```
JAPANESE_CHATACTERhttp://bit.ly/1GXY6npJAPANESE_CHATACTER。
```

**in Django**

OUTPUT:

```
JAPANESE_CHATACTER&lt;url&gt;https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29250195/&lt;/url&gt;JAPANESE_CHATACTER
```

it automatically converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it not well documented on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)?

```
def make_shorten_url(m):
    long_url = m.group(1)   # Access the capture group here
    import urllib
    import bitly_api
    login_name = 'my id'
    api_key = 'my secret key'
    bitly = bitly_api.Connection(login_name, api_key)
                           # .group() no more needed
    quote_url = urllib.quote(long_url, ':/?&=')
    try:
        result = bitly.shorten(quote_url)
    except:
        return long_url
    return result['url'].encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @shinriyo Sorry, I was away. Is your problem resolved?

Comment: yes! Thank you. My problem was my misunderstand my code myself.
And it is first time to know your country, Mauritius. I was recognized there are a lot of kindness peoples.